# Google Colab error: Import "tensorflow.keras.models" could not be resolved(reportMissingImports)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.__version__

!sudo pip3 install keras

from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, Flatten, Dropout, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
```

Error message:

```
Import "tensorflow.keras.models" could not be resolved(reportMissingImports)
>Import "tensorflow.keras.layers" could not be resolved(reportMissingImports)
>>Import "tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image" could not be resolved(reportMissingImports)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: as I know currently `keras` is part of `tensorflow` and you don't have to install it. Maybe you installed some old keras and it makes problem.

Comment: Hi! Could not replicate this issue in TF 2.8 version.  Could you  please share your Colab gist?

Answer (score 32):

this worked for me.

```py
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.models import Sequential, load_model
```

Answer (score 9):

```py
import tensorflow as tf
tf.__version__

!sudo pip3 install keras

from tensorflow.python.keras.engine.sequential import Sequential

from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, Flatten, Dropout, MaxPooling2D

image_data_generator = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

i had the same error , l did those steps
**step 01** : uninstall the existing tensorflow with this instruction

```
!pip uninstall tensorflow
```

step 02 : install this version i hope you find what you need in this version with this instruction

```
!pip install tensorflow==2.7.0
```

you can change the version of tensorflow if 2.7.0 not good for your code

Answer (score 1):

Issue solved.

Though the error: `Import "tensorflow.keras.models" could not be resolved(reportMissingImports)` prompts, it doesn't affect the entire code. My Tensorflow version is 2.8.0. I just found out that the problem is on the config of my cnn model.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it.

The problem was my version was too new. You just need to lower your TensorFlow version so that its suitable for your requirement.
I've lowered my version from 2.8.0 to 2.7.0 using
`pip install tensorflow==2.7.0.`

Check these images, the warning lines disappeared for me.

[Before I downgraded my TensorFlow version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgozk.png)

[After I downgraded my TensorFlow version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzKUg.png)

Comment: use code block to format the lines of code executed. It helps in better readability

Answer (score 0):

I believe keras is now installed as its own module when you pip install tensorflow, so you can remove the "tensorflow." from your import statements. So if you first:

```
pip3 install tensorflow
```

You can access specific models of keras like this:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using VScode, this is how I managed to solve the problem in python script

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential, load_model
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import LSTM, Dense
```

Answer (score -1):

**Using this command solved my issue
It is the only command you need!!!**

I tested all the methods but it didn't work finally this works

```
!sudo pip3 install keras
```

Comment: Watson21 already gave this answer a year and a half ago. Please don't repeat answers.

Comment: (And running `pip install` with `sudo` is almost always a bad idea. Don't mix PyPI packages with system packages.)