Import Error in VSCode: Unable to Resolve Import "tensorflow.keras.layers"
I am encountering an import error in Visual Studio Code when using TensorFlow. The specific error message is:
Import "tensorflow.keras.layers" could not be resolved

I have already installed TensorFlow using pip install tensorflow and verified that the package is installed correctly by running pip show tensorflow.
Here are the steps I have taken so far:

Verified that TensorFlow is installed by running pip show tensorflow, which shows the correct installation details.(you can see this Command entered in the picture below)

Checked that my VSCode Python interpreter is correctly set to the virtual environment where TensorFlow is installed.
Tried reloading the VSCode window and reinstalling TensorFlow.

Despite these steps, the import error persists. How can I resolve this import error in VSCode?
I also studied other questions, here asked in Stackoverflow. they said that I should change this setting it might be a problem with Execution Policy Settings. To fix it, you should try executing Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope Process
But this also didn't solve my problem!!
So I'd be thankful if you guys would say the other underlying causes for this weird error.
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
I added the Step of Checking the Tensorflow version]3


Check the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47265298/8663492
I think it's a similar one.

It might be the case that you have not selected the interpreter you want. Use Ctrl+Shift+P, and select the option "python: select interpreter". Then, select different interpreters. It should be one of them, which has the packages you installed to.

I think the problem mentioned by @AzuxirenLeadGuy is possible. Can you share with us how you completed the step of "Checked that my VSCode Python interpreter"? You can try to check it using : python -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.version)", and remember to share the output result.

@DennisLi Thnx for your Comment. I added the picture of your command: Checking my vscode interpreter

actually my error got solved with a very simple solution

https://stackoverflow.com/a/76540697/12129522 this was the solution for me!
